# Echo comma separated value from MySql in search bar separately

Tags: php, mysql, explode

### My DB

### `Name`      `Title`

`Abu,Ali`  `Red Shoes`

`Mia,Sarah`  `Yellow shoes`

I created a search bar using LIKE '%$keyword%'. When enter keyword for example Abu or Red shoes the result i want to be appear is:

### `Abu`

`Red Shoes`

### `Ali`

`Red Shoes`

I only get the result like this:

### `Abu,Ali`

`Red Shoes`

---

How can i separate the result without separating then in the DB...I need to store the data in comma value

Comment: `I need to store the data in comma value`. No, there are other ways you could store it. Learn about database normalisation.

Comment: You tagged this with `explode` already, and I guess we should be allowed to assume that you know how a basic loop over an array works ... so what more do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you get the values in php you can iterate over the names and use the explode function of php.
Please be aware that this database is set up to fail, it will very likely cause problems and headaches in the future. It is better to seperate the names into individual rows.
However if you really cannot do it any other way, this is how you can seperate the names (I assume you get the SQL result into a variable called $result)

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $names = explode(",", $row["Name"]);
        for($i = 0; $i < count($names); $i++){
            echo "Name: " . $names[$i] . "Title: " . $row["Title"];
            //In this for-loop you just iterate over the names and print them into 
            //the page. The first loop would be "Name: Abu Title: Red Shoes"
        }
    }

}
```